como firmar un documento xml para la facturación electronica en c#
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en C# para firmar un documento XML que se usa para facturación electrónica. El código que tengo actualmente firma correctamente el XML, pero necesito agregar algunos detalles adicionales:

Etiqueta Object con información del certificado
Política de firma: Necesito incluir la política de firma dentro de la etiqueta Object, siguiendo la especificación XAdES.

     public static string SignXml(string xml, RSA privateKey, string signatureId, 
     X509Certificate2 certificate)
    {
    if (certificate == null || privateKey == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("el certificado o la clave privada no existen");
    }
    
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;

    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("ext", 
    "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2");
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("ds", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("xades", "http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#");
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("sts", "http://www.dian.gov.co/schema/");

    try
    {
        doc.LoadXml(xml);

        // Find the UBLExtensions element
        XmlNode ublExtensionsNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//ext:UBLExtensions", nsmgr);
        if (ublExtensionsNode == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("No se encontró la etiqueta <ext:UBLExtensions> en el 
        XML.");
        }

        // Create UBLExtension and ExtensionContent elements
        XmlElement ublExtensionElement = doc.CreateElement("ext", "UBLExtension", 
        "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2");
        XmlElement extensionContentElement = doc.CreateElement("ext", "ExtensionContent", 
         "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2");

        // Append the new elements to the UBLExtensions element
        ublExtensionsNode.AppendChild(ublExtensionElement);
        ublExtensionElement.AppendChild(extensionContentElement);

        SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc)
        {
            SigningKey = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey(),
            SignatureId = signatureId // Adding the Signature ID
        };

        // Create a reference to be signed
        Reference reference = new Reference
        {
            Uri = "" // Leave this empty to sign the entire document
        };

        // Add an enveloped transformation to the reference
        XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
        reference.AddTransform(env);

        // Add a canonicalization transform to the reference
        XmlDsigC14NTransform c14Transform = new XmlDsigC14NTransform();
        reference.AddTransform(c14Transform);

        // Add the reference to the SignedXml object
        signedXml.AddReference(reference);

        KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
        keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(certificate));
        signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

        // Compute the signature
        signedXml.ComputeSignature();

        // Get the XML representation of the signature
        XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();
      extensionContentElement.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));

        return doc.OuterXml;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        throw new Exception("Error al firmar el XML: " + ex.Message);
        }
       }


Y cual seria el problema?

no se como podria agregar de manera correcta la etiqueta object y las politicas de la firma sin invalidar la firma, en la preguntá creo que especifique está parte
